# Overlay button not clickable

Tags: html, css

I am trying to make web-based slides myself, but I stumble on making a toolbar appear above each slide: the buttons are not clickable.
I reproduced this problem on this quasi-minimum working example. If you click on the button, it will not do anything, except click on the slide. However, the z-index of the button is greater than of the slide.

How can I leave the elements where they are (in the tree) and have the button to be clickable?

```css
#fullscreenbutton {
  z-index: 1001;
}
.slides {
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
  padding-bottom: 56.25%; /* 16:9 */
  position: relative;
  overflow: hidden;
}
.slide {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0; bottom: 0; left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  font-size: 1.5vw;
  padding: 20px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  z-index: 1000;
}
```

```html
<div id="app">
  <div class="slides" id="slides">
    <button id="fullscreenbutton" onclick="this.style.color='red'">Make me red</button>
    <div class="slide" ignore-position="current">
      this slide overrides everything
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: _"However, the z-index of the button is greater than of the slide"_ - You aren't setting the z-index of the button anywhere in your code. There is no element with the ID `#fullscreenbutton`. Also, z-index only works on position `relative / absolute / fixed` elements.

Comment: I just fixed that part, the problem is still there.

Comment: The button still is not using `position: relative`, `absolute` or `fixed` so the z-index will be ignored.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way to resolve this is by removing non-css actions from the underlying element:

```
.slide {
   ...
  pointer-events: none
}
```

[Fiddle Example](https://jsfiddle.net/ivanferrer/kf9yhnmv/)

Answer (score 1):

`div.slide` is in front of the button and captures all the events.

I think it would make sense to put all the controls in a separate, absolute `.div` that is positioned in front of the slides.

Answer (score 1):

Ok I found it, I just needed to set up

```
position:absolute;
```

on the button `#fullscreenbutton`.